# Why is it possible to call the no-argument version of init when the class doesn't provide an implementation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, inheritance

I've been reviewing the [Swift documentation on inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203), and there's one thing I don't think I really understand: It seems that I can call the default no-argument initializer on pretty much any Cocoa Touch class, even though according to the rules, it seems like I shouldn't be able to.

For example, consider the `NSNumber` class, which inherits directly from `NSObject`. `NSObject` defines a single designated initializer: `init()`. `NSNumber` defines a bunch of designated initializers (like `init(int value: Int32)`, etc.), but does *not* override `init()`.

According to the documentation, these are the rules:

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1:** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2:** If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its
>   superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
>   rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
>   definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
>   convenience initializers.
>
> These rules apply even if your subclass adds further convenience
>   initializers.

Since `NSNumber` *does* define its own designated initializers, I would expect that according to **Rule 1**, `NSNumber` would not inherit the `init()` initializer. But `init()` is included by the Xcode autocomplete, and it doesn't cause a compiler error.

The runtime behavior seems to differ between classes. `NSNumber` seems to crash when you call that initializer. `NSInputStream` (where I first encountered this issue) does not, but seems to not initialize subclass instance variables properly.

It seems like this should be a compiler error. Is this just a bug in Swift, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The reason NSNumber and other NS classes don't follow the Swift rules is because they are implemented purely in Objective-C.

Depending on how the subclass of NSObject is defined will determine how Swift can interact with it.

The most basic subclass will allow both `init()` and `init(value: String)` to be called via Swift:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;
- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSString *)value;
@end
```

A proper subclass implementation will make it so Swift can only call `init(value: String)` and will cause a compiler error if `init()` is called:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *value;
- (instancetype)initWithValue:(NSString *)value NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (instancetype)init __attribute__((unavailable("init is unavailable")));
@end
```

It seems like NSNumber is using something closer to the first approach